# Integration Test for Hosted Service in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, mstest, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a QueueTask Hosted service (.NET Core's new background service) that I'd like to test.  My queuedHosted service looks like so:

```
public QueuedHostedService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IBackgroundTaskQueue taskQueue, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    TaskQueue = taskQueue;
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<QueuedHostedService>();
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
    {
        while (false == stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var workItem = await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(stoppingToken);
            try
            {
                await workItem(scope.ServiceProvider, stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this._logger.LogError(ex, $"Error occurred executing {nameof(workItem)}.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It just reads tasks from the queue and executes them as they come in.  I've already verified that the Hosted Service is working in Production. I wrote a test for it like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Verify_Hosted_Service_Executes_Task()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, NullLoggerFactory>();
    services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var backgroundQueue = serviceProvider.GetService<IBackgroundTaskQueue>();

    var isExecuted = false;
    backgroundQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async (sp, ct) => {
        isExecuted = true;
    });

    await Task.Delay(10000);
    Assert.IsTrue(isExecuted);
}
```

However, my callback is never hit.  How can I get my task to execute on the Background Service?

**Edit**

I was mimicking the startup, and assumed my background service would just work,
but apparently my service is never started.

How is the Hosted Service normally Started from .NET Core?

Comment: In regards to "How to start your hosted service?" You should use [GenericHost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to run your `IHostedService`. You will also need to configure service dependencies.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Hosted services are started by the framework as part of the WebHost's start process

```
// Fire IHostedService.Start
await _hostedServiceExecutor.StartAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/15008b0b7fcb54235a9de3ab844c066aaf42ea44/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/WebHost.cs#L130)

via the `HostedServiceExecutor` which would take a collection of all the registered `IHostedService`, enumerate them and start them in turn

```
public HostedServiceExecutor(ILogger<HostedServiceExecutor> logger, IEnumerable<IHostedService> services)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _services = services;
}

public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        await ExecuteAsync(service => service.StartAsync(token));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.ApplicationError(LoggerEventIds.HostedServiceStartException, "An error occurred starting the application", ex);
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/15008b0b7fcb54235a9de3ab844c066aaf42ea44/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/HostedServiceExecutor.cs#L18)

But since you are testing the hosted service on its own, you have to act as the framework and start the service yourself.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Verify_Hosted_Service_Executes_Task() {
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, NullLoggerFactory>();
    services.AddHostedService<QueuedHostedService>();
    services.AddSingleton<IBackgroundTaskQueue, BackgroundTaskQueue>();
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>() as QueuedHostedService;

    var backgroundQueue = serviceProvider.GetService<IBackgroundTaskQueue>();

    await service.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);

    var isExecuted = false;
    backgroundQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async (sp, ct) => {
        isExecuted = true;
    });

    await Task.Delay(10000);
    Assert.IsTrue(isExecuted);

    await service.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: I had to use var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>(); instead of QueuedHostedService to get service to be populated.

Comment: @user1568891 `QueuedHostedService` was directly referring to the type they were using in their question.

Comment: @Nkosi When I just used the Type of my class that I also entered in AddHostedService, GetService returned null for me. It wouldn't return the type I entered in AddHostedService until I changed it to be IHostedService. Perhaps I was doing something else different though.

Comment: @user1568891 then the problem was with my code. Upon further review, the behavior you described is correct as I see no direct registration of that class with the service collection.

Comment: you can also get the new service with(especially yseful if you have multipleIHostedInstaces registered)
serviceProvider.GetServices<IHostedService>().OfType<YourType>().Single();

Comment: services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, NullLoggerFactory>();
Didn't work for me, I used 
services.AddLogging(config => config.AddDebug());

Comment: In my case the hosted service starts immediately without calling service.StartAsync as it does normally.