# Equivalent syntax of Moq's Mock.Get in Nsubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq, nsubstitute

I'm writing a unit test for my background service. It seems to be working if I use Moq framework but we are using NSubstitute within the team and would like to stick with that.

I was referring the code mentioned @[How can i write unit test for my background service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644654/how-can-i-write-unit-test-for-my-background-service).

I managed to convert the code syntax from Moq to NSubstitute except one line i.e. `Mock.Get(service)`.

Could anyone help me convert the below code to use NSubstitute instead of Moq or let me know the equivalent syntax of `Mock.Get(service)` in NSubstitute.

```
 IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
 services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<someobject>()); // Nsubstittute equivalent is services.AddSingleton(Substitute.For<someobject>());

 var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
 var service = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<someobject>();

 var hostedService = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>();
 await hostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
 await Task.Delay(2000);
 await hostedService.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None);

 var mock = Mock.Get(service);
 mock.Verify(_ => _.SendQuote(), Times.Once);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally since nsub works directly with the mocked interface, you want to hold on to it in a variable.

```
//Arrange
IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();    
var mock = Substitute.For<someobject>(); //<-- THE MOCK
services.AddSingleton(mock);
//...add your hosted service that depends on the mock as needed

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var hostedService = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostedService>();

//Act
await hostedService.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
await Task.Delay(2000);
await hostedService.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None);

//Assert
mock.Received().SendQuote(); //<-- assert the mock directly
```