# What to assert or verify while unit testing the BackgroundService in .Net core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, background-service

I have a linked question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60387013/while-unit-testing-a-net-core-3-1-background-service-unable-to-resolve-iconfig/60387252#60387252). I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644654/how-can-i-write-unit-test-for-my-background-service) and I'm trying to mock the dependencies in my Hosted Service. But I'm confused as to assert or verify what. I'm thinking to verify that `StartConsumption` on `Mock Kafka Topic Consumer Manager` gets invoked. But to set it up, it returns `void`. I'm not able to determine how to set up the predicate for the mock.

```
services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IKafkaTopicConsumerManager>(_ => 
    _.StartConsumption(
       It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(),
       It.IsAny<IMessageProcessingCapable>(),
       It.IsAny<string>(),
       It.IsAny<string>(),
       It.IsAny<List<string>>(),
       It.IsAny<string>(),
       It.IsAny<int>())==void
    ));
```

But at `void` it shows up invalid expression term. Below is my Worker.cs which is the `Hosted Service`.

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _consumerManager.StartConsumption(
            cancellationToken,
            _messageProcessor,
            _config.GetSection("Kafka:Servers").Get<string>(),
            _config.GetSection("ConsumerGroup").Get<string>(),
            _config.GetSection("Topics").Get<List<string>>(),
            _config.GetSection("Kafka:TopicSuffix").Get<string>(),
            _config.GetSection("ConsumerThreads").Get<int>());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the mock. Since the invoked member is void, then there is nothing to return. Thus no need to set it up to do anything.

```
services.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IKafkaTopicConsumerManage>());
```

What you can do, is verify that the mocked member was invoked after exercising the subject under test

```
var _mockedKafkaTopicConsumerManager = Mock.Get(serviceProvider.GetService<IKafkaTopicConsumerManage>());
_mockedKafkaTopicConsumerManager
    .Verify(c => c.StartConsumption(
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(), 
        _mockedMessageProcessor.Object,
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<List<string>>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<int>()
),Times.Once);
```