# .Net Core 3 Worker Integration Tests

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

For integration testing Asp.Net Core application we have [WebApplicationFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#basic-tests-with-the-default-webapplicationfactory). But how to test `Worker` (`HostedService`) that is not web application? I don't want to copy the whole DI configuration in SUT like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224146/integration-test-for-hosted-service-net-core). Is it possible to use original configuration and override some of dependencies like we do for web application in [WebApplicationFactory.WithWebHostBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#customize-the-client-with-withwebhostbuilder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any solution for Worker services integration testing hence I made adoption of `WebApplicationFactory`. The source code and usage example can be found here:
https://github.com/gao-artur/WorkerService.Testing

Answer (score 0):

I realize this an old post but you can use `WebApplicationFactory` to test your worker service. Check out my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77737308/4465532).